# Making Games Seem Late Middle Ages/Early Renissance

Tags: gm-techniques

What things can I do or resources can I tap to make my fantasy games (system-independent) seem more late middle ages/early renaissance? e.g., the world as envisioned in Lamentations of the Flame Princess, Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay, etc.

Comment: I was going to say that this might do better on a site suited to free-wheeling discussion... [but I see you already thought of that](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?725301-Making-Games-Seem-Late-Middle-Ages-Early-Renissance). ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Learn history** and use it to **make your setting plausible**. You should read such source as [The Pursuit of Glory: Europe 1648-1815](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pursuit-Glory-Europe-1648-1815/dp/014016667X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399654731&sr=1-1&keywords=in%20pursuit%20of%20glory) by Tim Blanning, [Reformation : Europe's House Divided 1490-1700](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Reformation-Europes-House-Divided-1490-1700/dp/0140285342/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399654780&sr=1-1&keywords=Reformation) by Diarmaid MacCulloch, 
[The Thirty Years War](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Thirty-Years-Review-Books-Classics/dp/1590171462/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399655084&sr=1-4&keywords=thirty%20years%20war)by Anthony Grafton, C. V. Wedgwood and Paul Kennedy, 
and [吾輩は猫である](http://www.amazon.co.uk/I-am-Cat-Tuttle-classics/dp/080483265X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399654808&sr=1-1&keywords=I%20am%20a%20cat) (I Am A Cat). The reasons for reading the first three should be obvious.  The last one is a fine example of how an isolated society opens up to the rest of the world -- in this case Meiji Japan.  What this will give you is a (short) overview of how the real world behaved, thought (fought?), and evolved during this exiting time.

But history is not necessary going to help all that much depending on how close you want the fictional world to be to the real world. However, studying history will help you understand how and why some events happened the way they happened. This will enable you to either extrapolate to your fictional world or (better yet) set events up as in history but with a twist: how would the Thirty Years War have been modified if a bunch of angels did turn up to help both sides?  Clearly, if angels helped only one side, that'll be way less dramatic.

Comment: These books are great resources, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

These are obviously very opinionated but these are elements I would use in my game to make it feel like its in this time period, but I hope they help.

## Visualisation

You'll need to do some research into the details of clothing, architecture and common life of the people of the pre-renaissance period to be able to set the scene effectively vocally. But you can also just show your party visual aids to show them the style so they better understand.

You will want to incorporate heraldry into the game in a big way; in medieval times, every noble family wanted everyone to know how important they were. They put their coat of arms, showing their heraldry, on banners, shields and anything else they owned to show their wealth and power. Since each heraldry is unique your game could have some simple, easily identifiable main families that govern large areas with smaller families inside those.

This can then tie into the social elements of your game. Players allying themselves with one family will inadvertently have negative interactions with others.

For combat I recommend checking out [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hcyYYg6Q9Y) For references see shows like Game of Thrones, where even though the setting is fantasy, the show is clearly set in a pre-renaissance period. You can also take a look at some [renaissance fairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_fair) for inspiration.

## Music

Music is a great help in setting the style of the game. Use ambient music that focuses on flutes, harps, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GRLRm9oKUM) is a great representation of the variety of music that can fit in the period.

## Characters

In medieval times only the very wealthy could afford to be educated and learn to read. So you may want to make your players illiterate unless they are born in good families. Also religion plays a major part of peoples lives. So along with the families they belong to  and their religion are the major pillars of their lives.

The way characters speak should also reflect that they are uneducated or simple but also the actual words they use should be more [Shakespearian](http://www.pangloss.com/seidel/Shaker/).

Try and reduce magic in the world, make it rare and special. If you think of Arthurian England wizards were few and far. It should be the same in your game. A wizard should be respected(feared) by the people.